# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.response.status')

Tags: ios, bugsnag

We are getting lots of this kind of errors on bugsnag and almost all of them from ios mobile devices with all browsers. What does this error imply?
[image: bugsnag example]

Comment: It's impossible to know without seeing where `e.response.status` is coming from. Also, it might be that your sourcemaps are messed up so Bugsnag isn't highlighting the right line that raised the error.

Comment: so, this isn't about localstorage at all?

Comment: Could be the case. I might check your sourcemaps because the error looks more like a problem with an asynchronous fetch or similar than a localStorage retrieval.